# Change the background of a div with jquery easing the process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking for a way to change the background of a div using jQuery and I found this question:

[change background image jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417485/change-background-image-jquery)

I made it and it's working. But, there's a way to ease the process? Like an fade-in/out?

Sorry for my english. And thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:**

```
.branding{
     min-height:530px;
     background-image:url(../images/brandings-0.jpg);
     background-repeat:no-repeat; 
     background-position:center;
}

var newBg = [
    'site/assets/images/brandings-1.jpg',
    'site/assets/images/brandings-2.jpg',
    'site/assets/images/brandings-3.jpg'];

    var i = 0;

var rotateBg = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if(i > 2)
        i=0;

    $('.branding').css({backgroundImage : 'url(' + newBg[i] + ')'});
}, 5000); 

<div class="branding"></div>
```

Comment: Please share your code snippet/jsFiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: fade css background image change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002351/jquery-fade-css-background-image-change)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533171/fade-background-image-in-and-out-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Try the following fiddle I created for you.
>
> > http://jsfiddle.net/ujyjcfea/1/

```
var i = 0;

var newBg = [
    'http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-2.jpg',
    'http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-1.jpg',
    'http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-4.jpg'];

var image = $('.branding');


image.css('background-image', 'url(http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-2.jpg)');


setInterval(function () {

    image.fadeOut(1000, function () {

        image.css('background-image', 'url(' + newBg[i++] + ')');

        image.fadeIn(1000);

    });

    if (i == newBg.length)

    i = 0;
}, 5000);
```

---

http://www.programming-free.com/2013/12/change-background-image-jquery.html

Comment: If I put some content in the body, will it fade the div and the content or only the background?

Comment: Yes (if the text is part of the .branding element), however if yo uput it in a container and add an additional element for the text, it will transition behind the text.
http://jsfiddle.net/ujyjcfea/11/

Answer (score 1):

**demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/RyGKV/643/

```
var i = 0;
var images = ['http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-5.jpg',               'http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-2.jpg', 'http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-1.jpg'];
var image = $('#slideit');

image.css('background-image', 'url(http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-5.jpg)');  //Initial Background image setup

setInterval(function () {
    image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
        image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
        image.fadeIn(1000);
    });
    if (i == images.length) i = 0;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: If I put some content in the body, will it fade the div and the content or only the background?